# How to specifically fprintf an array on a file

Tags: matlab

Lets say for example we have this array:

```
x =

    0.5920    0.4635
    0.6451    0.2118
   -0.1206   -0.6036
    0.2417    0.4773
    0.3029    0.5172
```

What code would I need to write in order to print in such a way that it looks like this:

```
    coords
    x1 0.5920    y1 0.4635
    x2 0.6451    y2 0.2118
    x3 -0.1206   y3 -0.6036
    x4 0.2417    y4 0.4773
    x5 0.3029    y5 0.5172
```

I've tried this:

```
x = gallery('uniformdata',[1,10],0);
y = gallery('uniformdata',[1,10],1);


[v,c] = voronoin([x(:) y(:)]); %returns an array V with vertices and a cell array C with a matrix for each cell of the diagram. 
c
for k = 1 : numel(c)
     c{k} = c{k}(c{k} ~= 1)
end

fileID = fopen('cords.txt' , 'w');
    for i=1:10
        coord = v(c{i},:);
        fprintf(fileID,'shape %d:\nx \t y\n', i);
        fprintf(fileID,'%.4f %.4f\n', coord(:,1), coord(:,2));

    end
    fclose(fileID);
```

but im getting an output like this:

```
shape 10:
x    y
0.5920 0.6451 %notice how the .6451 is on the right side when it should be on the bottom
-0.1206 0.2417
0.3029 0.4635
0.2118 -0.6036
0.4773 0.5172
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fprintf` function reads the input variables in a **column first** manner and sends each value to its appropriate place in the string. So, in your code what happens is that even when you specify two different vectors per `%.4f` in your code, Matlab ignores that ordering. It puts the first value of `coord(:, 1)` in the first `%.4f` and the second value of `coord(:, 1)` in the second `%.4f`. Then it breaks the line. Then it again picks up the third value from `coord(:, 1)` and puts it in the first `%.4f` and so on. It only picks values from `coord(:, 2)` when all values of the first vector are exhausted.

The simplest fix is to transpose the `coord` matrix and then input it to Matlab like this:

```
fprintf(fileID,'%.4f %.4f\n', coord.'); % .' tranposes the matrix
```

**Edit:**

To get the format as `x1 0.5920 y1 0.4635`, we can make use of the column first ordering that Matlab follows to access a variable

```
% First we make a new matrix that has each of the required elements for the desired format
% The index of x, the value of x, the index of y and the value of y
tempCoord = [1:size(coord, 1); coord(:, 1).'; 1:size(coord, 1); coord(:, 2).'];
% Now we change the string specification for fprintf
fprintf(fileID,'x%d %.4f y%d %.4f\n', tempCoord);
```

Why does this work?

If you look at `tempCoord`, you will see that each of its columns has the format needed for the string specifier, i.e., the index of x, the value of x, the index of y and the value of y

```
tempCoord =
   1.000000000000000   2.000000000000000   3.000000000000000   4.000000000000000   5.000000000000000
   0.592000000000000   0.645100000000000  -0.120600000000000   0.241700000000000   0.302900000000000
   1.000000000000000   2.000000000000000   3.000000000000000   4.000000000000000   5.000000000000000
   0.463500000000000   0.211800000000000  -0.603600000000000   0.477300000000000   0.517200000000000
```

Now each column becomes each row of the printed file and you get the following output:

```
x1 0.5920 y1 0.4635
x2 0.6451 y2 0.2118
x3 -0.1206 y3 -0.6036
x4 0.2417 y4 0.4773
x5 0.3029 y5 0.5172
```

Comment: Can you explain why ```coord.'``` fixes the problem? I understand it fixes the problem, but what does the ```.'``` do?

Comment: Also, I want to achieve this ```x1 0.5920    y1 0.4635```. I've tried this ```fprintf(fileID,'x%d %.4f y%d %.4f\n', i,(coord.'));```, but this is the output I am getting in the file ```x1 1.9914 y3.345587e-01 0.7785
x9.714147e-01 shape 2:```

Comment: The `.'` just transposes the matrix. I will update the answer so that  you can print `x1 0.5920 y1 0.4635`

Comment: `.'` is the shorthand notation for the [`transpose`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) operator.